Does firebase share the devices where the tests are performed?
We are running an instrumentation test in the Firebase TestLab.
This instrumentation test performs several benchmarks and stores the times it records.
But the times we get on Firebase devices are different from those we get on local devices.
If the times, they should not vary much:
Local device:

A = 0.5413
B = 0.4990
D = 0.5135

Variations occur in Firebase:

A = 0.5343
B = 2.5390
D = 0.4980

Does this mean that tests are being performed by other users while our test is running, and that is why we get a higher than normal value at some times?

No. All tests are performed using exclusive access to that one device.  The devices are only shared in the sense that devices are returned to the pool of available devices and wiped clean after the test completes.
